# Deleting unlabeled text from HTML via jquery

Tags: jquery, html, tags

I have the HTML codes below as shown in Firebug.

```
<div class="k-tabstrip-wrapper">

    <div id="testYearTab" class="yearTab k-widget k-header k-tabstrip" data-bind="source: chuva" data-role="tabstrip" tabindex="0" role="tablist">

        First element Second LastFirst element Second Last…

        <ul class="k-tabstrip-items k-reset">
            <li class="k-item k-state-default k-first" role="tab" aria-controls="testYearTab-1"></li>
            <li class="k-item k-state-default" role="tab" aria-controls="testYearTab-2"></li>
            <li class="k-item k-state-default" role="tab" aria-controls="testYearTab-3"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

---

Now, what I want is to delete the text "First element Second LastFirst element Second Last…" how to do that? FYI, the said text is not being placed to any tags like "h1" for an example.

BTW, the code above was being generated by kendoTabStrip.

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/nmmb0ffj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation this will work

```
$('#testYearTab').contents().eq(0).remove()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/66/)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the text node children of the element `#testYearTab` like

```
$('#testYearTab').contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#testYearTab:contains("First element")').remove();
```